# Use sed to fix weird symbols on tex file generated by publish function from miscellaneous Octave package

Tags: linux, command-line, sed, latex, octave

I have an Octave code that among other things outputs:

```
     (x - 5)⋅(x - 4)⋅(x - 3)⋅(x - 2)
   ───────────────────────────────
             24
```

When using publish function from Octave miscellaneous package, the corresponding latex code look like this:

```
  (x - 5)â‹…(x - 4)â‹…(x - 3)â‹…(x - 2)  
  â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€
             24
```

I tried using sed to replace the weird characters:

```
       sed -i -e 's/â‹…/$\cdot$/g' file.tex
       sed -i -e 's/â”€/-/g' file.tex
```

But nothing happens... Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Testing your data stored in a variable, works fine in my gnu sed 4.4 (without using -i switch though)

Comment: I can't reproduce it. I just noted that if i run `cat file.tex`, in cli appears just like the output of octave (not with the weird symbols)...